# How to reuse the Exoplayer instance and attach the same instance to the views?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-viewpager2

Suppose I have 2 fragment - PageOneFragment and PageTwoFragment

What if I want to reuse the player instance and attach the same instance to the views

How can I do this with ExoPlayer? and if I am using ViewPager2?

**My Instance**

```
SimpleExoPlayer player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
player.setPlayer(playerView1);
```